# How to create JSON Object using String?

Tags: java, android, json

I want to create a JSON Object using String.

Example : 
JSON `{"test1":"value1","test2":{"id":0,"name":"testName"}}`

In order to create the above JSON I am using this.

```
String message;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("test1", "value1");

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

jsonObj.put("id", 0);
jsonObj.put("name", "testName");
json.put("test2", jsonObj);

message = json.toString();
System.out.println(message);
```

I want to know how can I create a JSON which has JSON Array in it.

Below is the sample JSON.

```
{
  "name": "student",
   "stu": {
    "id": 0,
    "batch": "batch@"
  },
  "course": [
    {
      "information": "test",
      "id": "3",
      "name": "course1"
    }
  ],
  "studentAddress": [
    {
      "additionalinfo": "test info",
      "Address": [
        {
          "H.No": "1243",
          "Name": "Temp Address",
          "locality": "Temp locality",
           "id":33          
        },
        {
           "H.No": "1243",
          "Name": "Temp Address",
          "locality": "Temp locality", 
           "id":33                   
        },        
        {
           "H.No": "1243",
          "Name": "Temp Address",
          "locality": "Temp locality", 
           "id":36                   
        }
      ],
"verified": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

`org.json.JSONArray` may be what you want.

```
String message;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("name", "student");

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
item.put("information", "test");
item.put("id", 3);
item.put("name", "course1");
array.put(item);

json.put("course", array);

message = json.toString();

// message
// {"course":[{"id":3,"information":"test","name":"course1"}],"name":"student"}
```

Comment: How do I convert it back to a `JSONObject` from a string?

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("your_json_string");`

Comment: FYI that this will fail to parse JSON arrays (even though they are technically valid JSON). For example, trying `JSONObject("[{\"foo\":2, \"bar\": 3}]");` results in `A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`

Comment: JSONArray uses the "add" rather than the "put" method. Change `array.put(item);` to `array.add(item);`

Answer (score 13):

In contrast to what the accepted answer proposes, the documentation says that for *JSONArray()* you must use `put(value)` no `add(value)`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#put(java.lang.Object)

(Android API 19-27. Kotlin 1.2.50)

Answer (score 4):

If you use the gson.JsonObject you can have something like that:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

String jsonString = "{'test1':'value1','test2':{'id':0,'name':'testName'}}"
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString)
```

Comment: It worked for me, the simplest solution, thanks

Comment: updated code that worked for me
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{'test1':'value1','test2':{'id':0,'name':'testName'}}";
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);

        // Print the parsed JsonObject
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
}

Answer (score 3):

```
 String jsonString = "{'element1':'value1','element2':{'id':0,'name':'testName'}}";
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) JsonParser.parseString(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) can create json from an object.

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

    String message = U.objectBuilder()
            .add("course", U.arrayBuilder()
                    .add(U.objectBuilder()
                            .add("id", 3)
                            .add("information", "test")
                            .add("name", "course1")
                    ))
            .add("name", "student")
            .toJson();
    System.out.println(message);

// {
//   "course": [
//     {
//       "id": 3,
//       "information": "test",
//       "name": "course1"
//     }
//   ],
//   "name": "student"
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that worked for me

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{'test1':'value1','test2':{'id':0,'name':'testName'}}";
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);

        // Print the parsed JsonObject
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
}
```