# Converting byte[] to json and vice versa without jackson or gson

Tags: java, json

I have a legacy application which has been built with java 1.5, I need a conversion between byte[] and json but I cannot use jackson or gson, because they are in a higher version of java.
I have methods like these and I couldn't find a way to implement with [JSONObject](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html) :

```
public <T> T toObj(byte[] bytes, Class<T> responseType) {
    
}
```

Comment: I am a little bit in confusion. you want to invoke these two methods right? Why do you need to serialize in in json object? You just call declare a field of byte[] to call/consume these services.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build a library for basic http call to the rest services, in my library  i need such method which i couldn't implement

Comment: Has it been written in Java 1.5 or are you limited to a 1.5 version JVM ?

Comment: Yes, it's java 1.5. I cannot use higher version of java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it would be so easy, then `Jackson` or `Gson` was never be born.

I am affraid, that you have to declared deserializer for all of your objects manualy. This is not a rocket science, but it takes time to do it. This is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Data data = new Data(11, 12);
    String json = toJson(data);
    System.out.println(json);

    byte[] bytes = json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Data res = toDataObj(bytes);
    System.out.println(res.a);
    System.out.println(res.b);
}

public static String toJson(Data data) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("a", data.a);
    jsonObj.put("b", data.b);
    return jsonObj.toString();
}


public static Data toDataObj(byte[] bytesClass) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(bytesClass, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Data data = new Data(0, 0);
    data.a = jsonObject.getInt("a");
    data.b = jsonObject.getInt("b");
    return data;
}

public static class Data {

    int a;
    int b;

    public Data(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

**Here you can get more info:**

- [How to create JSON Object using String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117148/how-to-create-json-object-using-string)
- [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: 1+, any other solution without JSONObject to utilize generic?

Comment: Try to use old version of `Jackosn` or `Gson` that works under `java 5`